# Registering an app with Google Cloud Messaging

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to understand how an app is registered with Google Cloud messaging. I'm looking at the code in the Google Play app for this which looks like this:

```
paramVarArgs = a(paramVarArgs);
Log.v("GCMRegistrar", "Registering app " + paramContext.getPackageName() + " of senders " + paramVarArgs);
Intent localIntent = new Intent("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER");
localIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.gsf");
localIntent.putExtra("app", PendingIntent.getBroadcast(paramContext, 0, new Intent(), 0));
localIntent.putExtra("sender", paramVarArgs);
paramContext.startService(localIntent);
```

I don't quite understand how the app that is being registered finally receives an intent as this seems to be sending the intent to the app with the package name com.google.android.gsf (Google services framework). I looked at the service that is invoked with the REGISTER action in gsf app, but it doesn't seem to be sending a broadcast either. I am quite confused about how this all works. Could someone please explain? Thanks a lot in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

If you will check the [Registering Client Apps](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/registration) document :

[image]

---

In the [Instance ID API](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/)

> Instance ID provides a unique ID per instance of your apps. You can implement Instance ID for [Android](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/guides/android-implementation) and [iOS](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/guides/ios-implementation) apps.

### Instance ID lifecycle

> 1. The Instance ID service issues an **`InstanceID`** when your app comes online. The **`InstanceID`** is backed by a public/private key pair with the private key stored on the local device and the public key registered with the Instance ID service.
> 2. Your app can request a fresh **`InstanceID`** whenever needed using the **`getID()`** method. Your app can store it on your server if you have one that supports your app.
> 3. Your app can request tokens from the Instance ID service as needed using the **`getToken()`** method, and like **`InstanceID`**, your app can also store tokens on your own server. All tokens issued to your app belong to the app's **`InstanceID`**.
> 4. Tokens are unique and secure, but your app or the Instance ID service may need to refresh tokens in the event of a security issue or when a user uninstalls and reinstalls your app during device restoration. Your app must implement a listener to respond to token refresh requests from the Instance ID service.

[image]

Here is a code sample for generating an ID:

```
String iid = InstanceID.getInstance(context).getId();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I was trying to ask what happens in terms of the interaction between the GCM service client app and the subscriber app. It seems there is an intent which contains a pending intent that also wraps an empty intent in it. What's the purpose of this?